# How to use a template function with multiple parameters in a template class C++

Tags: c++, class, templates

I'm trying to work on a question for a project in class where our data structures and methods are already pre-defined. It's my job to implement some functions that use these templates.

For example, I'm supposed to create a follows function, that does this: if I did `follows(q)` where `q = {"h", "e", "l", "l", "o", "w", "r"}` and `q` is of type `ArrayQueue`, it would create an `ArrayMap` that holds a single queue value as a key and a set of values that is next to that queue value.

If I looked inside the map, it would look like this:

```
Key -> Set Containing the Values
h -> set[e]
e -> set[l]
l -> set[l, o]
o -> set[w]
w -> set[r]
```

Now, I'm supposed to implement this function by using this template signature:

```
template<class T>
ics::ArrayMap<T,ics::ArraySet<T>> follows (const ics::ArrayQueue<T>& q) 
{
}
```

Although I understand the general logic behind how I would do this, I do need one thing: to be able to access and update the second parameter in the returned `ArrayMap`, which is `ics::ArraySet<T>`

So how would I call this `ArraySet` as a variable to do modifications on?

Comment: How does `this` come into the picture? Isn't `follows` supposed to be a free function, or is it a member function of some class? Anyway, to get help with a homework problem, you need to show what you've tried so far.

Comment: @Praetorian You are right, I believe it is just a free function. That was my mistake. That being said, is it possible to reference the second parameter `ics::ArraySet<T>`?

Comment: That depends on `ArrayMap`. For instance, with `std::map`, `operator[]` is one of the ways to get a reference to the `mapped_type`. `std::map::operator[]` will even default construct a `mapped_type` if it doesn't already contain the key you pass to it.

Comment: @Praetorian using the `operator[]` on `ArrayMap` just returns the value associated with the key, where each key is the index. So `map[e]` is basically saying `map[1]` and it ends up returning the value associated with that map. In this case, it would return `set[l]`.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by *`map[e]` is basically saying `map[1]`*, but assuming `ArrayMap::operator[]` returns a reference to the value associated with that key, then all you have to is call whatever member function of `ArrayQueue` that allows you to add another element to the queue.

Answer (score 0):

From your description it sounds like you should be able to do the following:

```
ics::ArraySet<T>& followers = the_array_map[x];
```

Assuming that you have a variable `the_array_map` which holds the follower map that you are constructing (and returning from the function).

Now you can update `followers` by appending the desired element to it.